# Script fails to run properly in cron.daily but works fine if I run it myself in the terminal

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a simple script to backup my Django database. I put it in /etc/cron.daily to run everyday. Here is the simple code:

```
#! /bin/bash

cd /home/username
mv backups old_backups
cd myproject
source env/bin/activate
python3 manage.py dbbackup
python3 manage.py mediabackup
rm -r ../old_backups
```

Running the script on my own works fine. Each day when I check to see the backups folder, it's gone along with the old_backups folder. Re-running the script manually will create the backups folder and back up my database properly.

Does anyone know what could be causing this script to "sort of" run in cron.daily when it works perfectly when run in a terminal?

Comment: any error message?

Comment: Add this to your cron line: `>/tmp/out.txt 2>/tmp/err.txt` and look at these files.  It may point out what is going on.  You could add `-x` to your first line to get even more debug messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by two issues. The first is that cron jobs are run by root by default. Normally that would be okay, but the proper python packages are not installed in my virtualenv due to pip defaulting to system-wide installations for some reason. I never felt like figuring out what was wrong there and just went with it.

I fixed this issue by running the python commands as my normal user instead of root:

```
sudo -u username python3 manage.py dbbackup
sudo -u username python3 manage.py mediabackup
```

I have implemented this fix and ran the script as root with success. I will now wait until it successfully runs as a cron job before marking this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like cron is not finding your `python3` binary.
Try using the command `which python3`, then find the path to your python version and then use this as an absolute path in your cron.

like `/usr/bin/python3 manage.py dbbackup` instead of `python3 manage.py dbbackup`

Comment: Thank you for your response. It seemed like a good idea, but I still get the same behavior after changing `python3` to `/usr/bin/python3`. `which` gave the same path you said.
I'm curious if this may have something to do with permissions, with scripts in `/etc/cron.daily/` *not* running under my normal user account.

Comment: @user2023630 could you provide some logs? you could try to pipe them to a file like `/usr/bin/python3 manage.py dbbackup > /home/username/dbbackup_out.log`

Comment: I tried adding logs as you suggested. The log files are created, but nothing is in them. The program still fails to run properly.

Comment: @user2023630 maybe you should add the code of your `manage.py` to your question, the issue might be in it

Comment: I have updated my question with the code for `manage.py`.

Comment: @user2023630 where is your manage.py located? could you try to add the absolute path to it aswell? like `/usr/bin/python3 /home/username/manage.py dbbackup`

Comment: Hey, so, I'm sorry. No dice. My manage.py is located in a fodler within my home folder. Thanks a ton for sticking with me up to this point. I'm willing to stick with you further if you are.

Comment: @user2023630 you could remove the catch part from you python script and see if after that you get an error in your output file

Comment: So, I'm almost 100% sure this fails because cron jobs are run as root by default. I tried switching to root and running this manually in a terminal and it failed with `ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?`
I think this is *not* because I fail to activate my virtual environment, but rather installing software with pip while in a virtualenv actually still installed the packages *system* wide.
This is an issue I've had for awhile and just shrugged it off.